# Format a list from a .txt file into a table using php

Tags: php

I have a text file that contains a list, with uppercase titles and then all lowercase list items. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get this converted into a table format. I've been able to do this a lot easily with a .txt tab delimited as the data was nice and organized from the source. However this source is awful and the data is not organized. So for example the list would look like this:

```
ALL UPPERCASE TITLE 1
lowercase description line a
lowercase description line e
lowercase description line c
ALL UPPERCASE TITLE 2
lowercase description line f
lowercase description line b
ALL UPPERCASE TITLE 3
lowercase description line c
lowercase description line b
```

I'm very new to php and think I'm in over my head, My question simplified is: 
Is this possible? Next questions is what functions should I learn in depth to achieve my goal?

Below is the garbage code I've been fighting with forever and as you can see I think I'm far from getting it close to correct.

```
<?php

$file = file("file.txt");

print "<tr><td><b>Item</b></td><td><b>Price</b></td></tr>";     

foreach($file as $line){ 
$line = trim($line); 
$product = foreach($line as $testcaseUP){
if (ctype_upper($testcase)) {
    print " $testcase \n";
}   
 }
$description = foreach($line as $testcaseLOWER){
if (ctype_lower($testcaseLOWER)) {
    print " $testcaseLOWER \n";
}   
 }
print "<tr class='itemproduct'><td class='product'>$product[0]</td><td>class='price'>$description[0]</td></tr>"; 
 }
?>
```

And here is what I was using for my tab delimeted .txt files which works great:

```
<?php
$file = file("file.txt");

print " 
<tr><td><b>Item</b></td><td><b>Price</b></td><td><b>Savings</b></td><td><b>Amount</b>     </td><td><b>Where</b></td></tr>";

foreach($file as $line){ 
$line = trim($line); 
$split = explode("\t",$line); 
print "<tr class='itemproduct'><td class='product'>$split[0]</td><td>   class='price'>$split[1]</td><td class='amount'>$split[2]</td><td class='sale'>$split[3]     </td><td class='where'>$split[4]</td> </tr>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: It would help with asking a question here if you showed the output as currently produced, and then also show an example of what you want it to look like.

Comment: Hmmm this is tricky as it currently produces nothing, however i can post the code that i know works for the other data format (tab delimited) but I felt that may be too confusing as they are different scenarios completely. Basically I am trying to avoid having to try to convert the info to a tab delimited style as it would take hours and hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the contents of your file. A generic way of doing it would be this.

`file('file.txt')` is returning your files contents as a one dimensional array. 
Each line is an element of the array. Once you loop through it, you can't loop through it again the way you are doing it.

your foreach is not returning anything so remove the =.

Use something like this and then format it the way you want
Assuming contents of file to be

Assuming file.txt:

```
TITLE
line
line
TITLE
line
```

The php :

```
<?php

    $file = file("file.txt");
    echo '<table>';


foreach($file as $line){ 
$line = trim($line);
//check if all uppercase 

 if (ctype_upper($line)) {
    echo" <tr><th>$line</th></tr>";
 }   

//else check if all lowercase

else if (ctype_lower($line)) {
    echo" <tr><td>$line</td></tr> \n";
 }   
}

?>
```

For your second question:

The php manual is a very good resource and it is there for a reason. You don't need to memorise any function. Understand how the language works and keep referring to the manual. Soon with time you will know while particular functions are used regularly.

Comment: This should be enough to push me in the right direction and get me practising and playing with the code a lot more. Thanks a lot! This example works well but my file is formatted so bad the results are wonkey but this gives me lots to work with, thanks again!